# Using python to build a latex document

Tags: python, latex

I have a script I have written in python which pulls data from a bunch of files on my computer which change daily. I want to insert the results into a latex template so that I can review the summary.

What is the best way to open a file and insert text into it at a specific point?

Preferably using a python, but I'm open to other tools if there is something better.

Thanks
Russ

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: I'm not really sure where to start. The only thing I can think of is to up the latex in a giant string broken up by where I put the outputs. 
I figure there is a better way to do it, but I haven't found anything on google.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it all from within python using the pylatex library. 
https://github.com/JelteF/PyLaTeX

This way you only have to run the python file every day.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it.

It seems to me the best way is to have python output low level latex code, then use latex's command \input to pull that code into a larger document.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents